# How to efficiently implement forward fill in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

How can I efficiently implement the fill forward logic (inspired for pandas `ffill`) for a vector shaped NxLxC (batch, sequence dimension, channel). Because each channel sequence is independent this can be equivalent to working with a tensor shaped (N*C)xL.

The computation should keep the torch variable so that the actual output is differentiable.

I managed to make something with advanced indexing, but it is L**2 in the memory and number of operations, so not very great and gpu friendly.

---

Example:

Assuming you have the sequence `[0,1,2,0,0,3,0,4,0,0,0,5,6,0]` in a tensor shaped `1x14` the fill forward will give you the sequence `[0,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,6,6]`.

An other example shaped `2x4` is `[[0, 1, 0, 3], [1, 2, 0, 3]]` which should be forward filled into `[[0, 1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3]]`.

---

Method used today:

We use the following code that is highly unoptimized but still faster than non vectorized loops:

```
def last_zero_sequence_start_indices(t: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    """
    Given a 3D tensor `t`, this function returns a two-dimensional tensor where each entry represents
    the starting index of the last contiguous sequence of zeros up to and including the current index.
    If there's no zero at the current position, the value is the tensor's length.

    In essence, for each position in `t`, the function pinpoints the beginning of the last contiguous
    sequence of zeros up to that position.

    Args:
    - t (torch.Tensor): Input tensor with shape [Batch, Channel, Time].

    Returns:
    - torch.Tensor: Three-dimensional tensor with shape [Batch, Channel, Time] indicating the starting position of
        the last sequence of zeros up to each index in `t`.
    """

    # Create a mask indicating the start of each zero sequence
    start_of_zero_sequence = (t == 0) & torch.cat([
        torch.full(t.shape[:-1] + (1,), True, device=t.device),
        t[..., :-1] != 0,
    ], dim=2)

    # Duplicate this mask into a TxT matrix
    duplicated_mask = start_of_zero_sequence.unsqueeze(2).repeat(1, 1, t.size(-1), 1)

    # Extract the lower triangular part of this matrix (including the diagonal)
    lower_triangular = torch.tril(duplicated_mask)

    # For each row, identify the index of the rightmost '1' (start of the last zero sequence up to that row)
    indices = t.size(-1) - 1 - lower_triangular.int().flip(dims=[3]).argmax(dim=3)

    return indices
```

Comment: Can you share some code to illustrate the problem and your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach to this problem, without creating TxT matrix:

```
import torch
def forward_fill(t: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    n_dim, t_dim = t.shape
    # Generate indices range
    rng = torch.arange(t_dim)
    
    rng_2d = rng.unsqueeze(0).repeat(n_dim, 1)
    # Replace indices to zero for elements that equal zero
    rng_2d[t == 0] = 0
    
    # Forward fill of indices range so all zero elements will be replaced with previous non-zero index.
    idx = rng_2d.cummax(1).values
    t = t[torch.arange(n_dim)[:, None], idx]
    return t
```

Note that this is a solution for 2D input but can be easily modified for more dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

This one avoid using any loops, torch.tril() and torch.argmax() functions are optimized.

```
import torch
    def forward_fill(t: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
      """
      Efficiently implements forward fill on a PyTorch tensor.
    
      Args:
        t (torch.Tensor): Input tensor with shape [Batch, Channel, Time].
    
      Returns:
        torch.Tensor: Output tensor with the same shape as the input tensor, but with the
          missing values filled in with the last non-missing value in each sequence.
      """
    
      # Convert input tensor to 2D
      flattened_tensor = t.view(-1, t.size(-1))
    
      # Extract lower triangular part of the tensor
      lower_triangular = torch.tril(flattened_tensor)
    
      # Find index of the rightmost non-zero element in every row
      indices = flattened_tensor.size(-1) - 1 - lower_triangular.int().flip(dims=[1]).argmax(dim=1)
    
      # Set values of the tensor to the corresponding values in the last row,
      # starting at index found in the previous step
      flattened_tensor[torch.arange(flattened_tensor.size(0)), indices] = flattened_tensor[-1]
    
      # Convert tensor back to the original shape
      return flattened_tensor.view(t.shape)
```

following here is example how use forward_fill():

```
# Create tensor with some missing values
t = torch.tensor([
    [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0],
    [1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0],
])

# Fill in the missing values using the `forward_fill()` function
filled_t = forward_fill(t)

# Print the filled-in tensor
print(filled_t)
```

output:

```
tensor([[0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6],
       [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6]])
```

Answer (score 0):

the shortest way i could come up with, using a mask to identify the last zero sequence start positions, and then a few indexing and permutation operations to create the final output.

```
def fill_seq_with_last(seq: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
    idx = torch.ones_like(seq, dtype=torch.int64) * (len(seq))
    idx[seq != 0] = t.nonzero()[:, -1]
    idx = torch.tril(idx)
    idx[idx == 0] = (len(seq))
    idx = idx.permute(1, 0)[torch.arange(0, len(seq)), seq != 0].add(1)
    return seq[torch.arange(len(seq)).unsqueeze(0)] = seq[torch.arange(len(seq)).unsqueeze(0), idx].unsqueeze(-1)
```

using advanced indexing to extract the values at these indices and set them as the fill forward values. This solution is efficient and can be easily adapted for batched sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution which works with inputs of arbitrary dimension and an arbitrary fill dimension.

```py
@torch.jit.script
def forward_fill_jit(t, dim=-1, fill_what=0, inplace=False):
    """Forward fill arbitrary dimension Pytorch tensor
    over specific axis

    Args:
        t (tensor): tensor with values to forward fill
        dim (int): dimension to fill
        fill_what (float): value to be replaced
        inplace (bool): whether to make a copy of `t`

    Returns:
        t (tensor): tensor with filled in values
    """
    if not inplace:
        t = t.clone()

    # move fill dim to the front to keep indexing simple
    t = t.moveaxis(dim, 0)
    last = torch.full_like(t[0], fill_what)
    for i in range(t.shape[0]):
        t[i] = t[i].where(t[i]!=fill_what, last)
        last = t[i]

    # move fill dim back to original location
    return t.moveaxis(0, dim)
```

Testing:

```py
>>> x = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0, 3], [1, 2, 0, 3]])

>>> forward_fill(x)
tensor([[0, 1, 1, 3],
        [1, 2, 2, 3]])

>>> forward_fill_jit(x)
tensor([[0, 1, 1, 3],
        [1, 2, 2, 3]])
```

Performance:

```py
from contexttimer import Timer

x = torch.tensor([[0, 1, 0, 3], [1, 2, 0, 3]]).tile(1000000, 1)

with Timer(prefix='forward_fill'):
    forward_fill(x)
with Timer(prefix='forward_fill_jit'):
    result = forward_fill_jit(x, inplace=True)
```

```
forward_fill took 0.102 seconds
forward_fill_jit took 0.007 seconds
```